# Does the Argument Principle for Winding Numbers have an Area Integral Analog (by Stokes' Theorem)?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, complex-integration, stokes-theorem, winding-number

The [Argument Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle) concerns a loop integral, and is used to relate the number of zeros and poles in the interior of the region enclosed by the loop. Does this principle have an area-integral analog, by [Stokes' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem), for instance?

Is the solution as simple as taking the derivative of $\frac{f'}{f}$ to make it into an area integral? Will the subtleties arising from complex analysis still hold? I could use any references on this matter. Apologies for these naive-sounding questions, but I am only getting started on understanding the complex nature of these theorems.

This question was motivated by an attempt to confirm some numerical winding number computations (using logarithms), against a discretized area integral.

Comment: The problem with applying Stokes' theorem here is that $f'/f$ has poles, but Stokes' theorem requires the thing you're integrating to be smooth on your manifold with boundary.